# Content is breaking with each other when forwarding

Tags: css, html-table, outlook, html-email

I'm creating an email templates using Marketo app. Once  created, I tried sending a sample mail to myself and it all looks good:

[image: looks good]

As you can see all the elements [table] shows fine, all together and neat, but when I try forwarding the same email, this happens:

[image: not good]

As you can see the header is broken from the body. This also happens for the footer. Why is this happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <title>Mizona</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #logo img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }

      td {
        word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; font-family:'Verdana', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; 
      }
      
      #content-subsection-right-img td, #content-subsection-plain td, #content-subsection-left-img td { 
        color: #555555;
      }

      .desktop-only {
        display: block;
      }

      .mobile-only {
        display: none;
      }

      .align-center {
        text-align: center; 
      }

      .align-right {
        text-align: right; 
      }


      .no-spacing {
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }
      
      .pad-cell5 td{
        padding: 5px !important;
      }
      
      .mobile-center {
        text-align: left !important;
      }

      #socialicons img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
        border: none;
      }
      
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      
      #graphic img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
      }

      table[class="body"] .columns td.one {
        width: 8.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.one {
        width: 8.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.two {
        width: 16.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.two {
        width: 16.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.three {
        width: 25% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.three {
        width: 25% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.four {
        width: 33.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.four {
        width: 33.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.five {
        width: 41.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.five {
        width: 41.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.six {
        width: 50%;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.six {
        width: 50%;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.seven {
        width: 58.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.seven {
        width: 58.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.eight {
        width: 66.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.eight {
        width: 66.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.nine {
        width: 75% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.nine {
        width: 75% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.ten {
        width: 83.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.ten {
        width: 83.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.eleven {
        width: 91.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.eleven {
        width: 91.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.twelve {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.twelve {
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      .pad-right-5 {
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .pad-right-10 {
        padding-right: 10px;
      }

      .pad-top-10 {
        padding-top: 10px;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .pad-right-10 {
          padding-right: 0px;
        }

        .desktop-only {
          display: none !important;
        }

        .mobile-only {
          display: block;
        }

        #logo img {
          width: 100% !important;
        }

        #logo-mobile img {
          width: 80% !important;
        }
        #graphic img {
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        *[class].center {
          text-align:center !important;
          margin:0 auto !important;
        }
        *[class].bottom-pad{ padding-bottom:35px !important;}
        table[class="body"] table.columns td {
          width: auto !important;
        }

        .social-icon td img {
          width: 40px !important;
          height: 40px !important;
        }
      }
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body style="width:100% !important; min-width:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; text-align:left; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; background:#eeeeee; color: #555555;"> 
    <table class="body" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;  vertical-align:top; text-align:left; height:100%; width:100%; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; background:#eeeeee; margin:0; padding:0; " bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
      <tbody> 
        <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
          <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; "> 
            <center style="width:100%; min-width:600px; "> 
              <table class="container" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
                <tbody> 
                  <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                    <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; margin:0; padding:0;" align="left" valign="top" width="600"> 
                      <table class="row" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:100%; position:relative; display:block; padding:0px; "> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                            <td class="wrapper last center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; position:relative; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                              <table class="twelve columns center desktop-only" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:600px; padding:0; display:table !important; "> 
                                <tbody> 
                                  <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                                    <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                                      <div class="mktEditable" id="logo" style="" mktoname="logo">
                                        <p style="margin:0px;"> <img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-header-digest-general-v2.1.jpg" alt="eO Logo White.png" constrain="true" imagepreview="false" style="max-width: 600px;" /> </p>
                                      </div></td> 
                                  </tr> 
                                </tbody> 
                              </table> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table> </td> 
                  </tr> 
                </tbody> 
              </table> 
              <table class="container mktoContainer" id="template-wrapper" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="title-date" mktoname="title/date"> 
                  <td> 
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr bgcolor="#2EA049"> 
                          <td style="color:#ffffff; padding: 10px 40px" align="left" valign="middle"> 
                            <div class="mktEditable" id="title" style="" mktoname="title-date">
                              <p style="margin: 0px;">Volume 4 | Issue 11 | 2018</p>
                            </div> </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="content-general" mktoname="general content"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="intro" style="margin-top: 20px;" mktoname="intro">
                      <h3 style="color: #88c34d; text-align: center;">Trust the Asset. Trust the Transaction.™</h3> 
                      <p>More and more players across industries are realizing the advantages of digital transformation, making it a competitive necessity for companies to harness digital solutions. Our own rapid growth mirrors this trend, with eOriginal recently being named one of the fastest growing companies in the country.</p> 
                      <p>Entering into 2019, eOriginal knows becoming part of the auto finance digital ecosystem is essential to achieving your business goals. To take full advantage of this continued growth, please join our upcoming webinar which is focus on the auto finance industry. Learn more about digital best practices and how originators and lenders can prioritize tech stack building and expansion.</p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-title" mktoname="subsection-title"> 
                  <td valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsection" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
                      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>eOriginal Named to Deloitte's Technology Fast 500™ </b></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-left-imgf16aafbb-fc4e-4e27-b799-256623b49daa" mktoname="mod-subsection-left-img-1"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="content-subsection-left-imgf16aafbb-fc4e-4e27-b799-256623b49daa" mktoname="content-subsection-left-img">
                      <table class="columns"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr valign="top"> 
                            <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="https://www.eoriginal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Random-image-_0005_iStock-511197926-1024x683.jpg" width="100%" /></p> </td> 
                            <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing">For the second consecutive year, eOriginal was named to Deloitte’s Technology Fast 500™, a ranking of the 500 fastest growing technology, media, telecommunications, life sciences and energy tech companies in North America. eOriginal's growth of 266 percent reaffirms its status as a leader in digital lending transformation and management.</p> <p class="no-spacing"><a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/press-releases/eoriginal-ranked-on-deloittes-2018-technology-fast-500/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Read more</b></a></p> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-titlef7e9c286-1eb5-44f6-9d0b-5b28ac2afd8d" mktoname="subsection-title-1"> 
                  <td valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsectionf7e9c286-1eb5-44f6-9d0b-5b28ac2afd8d" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
                      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>Live Webinar: Building an End-to-End eContracting Experience in Auto Finance</b></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-right-img21690d4b-48d7-4fae-a245-7fbbe7765aba" mktoname="mod-subsection-right-img-1"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="content-subsection-right-img21690d4b-48d7-4fae-a245-7fbbe7765aba" mktoname="content-subsection-right-img">
                      <table class="columns"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr valign="top"> 
                            <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing">Whether you provide direct or indirect lending, meeting the demands of today’s auto finance market means going digital is no longer a matter of ‘if’ but ‘when’. Join defi SOLUTIONS Chief Operating Officer Lana Johnson and eOriginal's Director of FinTech Strategies John Jacobs for insights on end-to-end digital auto financing processes, from origination to asset monetization through warehouse financing or securitization.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p class="no-spacing"><a href="http://info.eoriginal.com/W-DEC-V-18_Live-Event-LP.html?Lead_Source=Website&amp;Specific_Lead_Source=W-DEC-V-18&amp;Digital_Source=Website" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Register Now</b></a></p> </td> 
                            <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing"><br /><a href="http://info.eoriginal.com/W-OCT-MG-18_Live-Event-LP.html?Lead_Source=Webinar&amp;Specific_Lead_Source=W-OCT-MG-18&amp;Digital_Source=N-SEP-G-18" target="_blank"></a></p> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Cover Defi Solutions.jpg" height="151" width="269" /></p> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-title3ccba291-3d31-4b47-8f3e-4c143fa31497" mktoname="subsection-title-clone"> 
                  <td valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsection3ccba291-3d31-4b47-8f3e-4c143fa31497" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
                      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>Case Study: MotoLease Selects eOriginal to Digitally Transform Powersports Financing</b></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-left-img" mktoname="mod-subsection-left-img"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="content-subsection-left-img" mktoname="content-subsection-left-img">
                      <table class="columns"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr valign="top"> 
                            <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/eO_Job-327_CS_MotoLease_COVER_01112018.png" width="178" height="252" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /></p> </td> 
                            <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing">Driven by a vision to disrupt the powersports leasing segment, MotoLease turned to eOriginal to adopt best practices in eSignature and digital asset management. This case study highlights how transformative digital lending technology drove the company's dramatic growth to corner 75 percent of the powersports leasing market. <a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/blog/motoleases-commitment-to-innovation-drives-dramatic-growth/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Read more</b></a></p> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
              </table> 
              <table class="container" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
                <tbody> 
                  <tr bgcolor="#2EA049"> 
                    <td class="two-column" style="font-size: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table width="100%">
                      <tr>
                      <td width="50%" valign="top">
                      <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 20px 40px;"> <a href="http://go.eoriginal.com/JB3eB005bE0cHk00O000000" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff">eOriginal.com</a> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                        <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%"> 
                                  <tbody> 
                                    <tr> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://twitter.com/eOriginal/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-twitter-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/57606" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="LinkedIn" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-linkedin-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/eOriginal/58932553996/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-facebook-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;" width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/eo-insights/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Blog" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-blog-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                    </tr> 
                                  </tbody> 
                                </table> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      <![endif]--> </td> 
                  </tr> 
                  <tr bgcolor="#353937"> 
                    <td class="two-column" style="font-size: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table width="100%">
                      <tr>
                      <td width="50%" valign="top">
                      <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> <img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-footer-logo-v2.2.png" width="200" /><br /><br /> <span>© 2018 eOriginal, Inc. All rights reserved.</span> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                        <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> The Warehouse at Camden Yards<br /> 351 W. Camden St., Suite 800<br /> Baltimore, MD 21201<br /><br /> SALES <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-935-1776</span><br />SUPPORT <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-364-3578</span> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      <![endif]--> </td> 
                  </tr> 
                </tbody> 
              </table> 
            </center></td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for better understanding, provides your code.

Comment: done @AsiyaFatima

Comment: http://premailer.dialect.ca/
 https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner-v2.html checkout these URL's

Comment: already tried, doesnt work @AsiyaFatima

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really anything you can do to prevent this. It's well known across email development that forwarding trashes any and all email layouts in any number of ways depending on the client being used.

Best bet is to try and avoid suggesting users forward the email on and provide a 'send to a friend' landing page instead. Also informing colleagues/clients of the same and making sure they don't forward between each other. Alternatives for them are to send any tests on as attachments OR sending tests directly from your ESP.

Useful Litmus blog post going into the issue a bit more [here](https://litmus.com/blog/when-forwarded-emails-break)